# Trying to take the line from a logfile, remove some text, and put it into a new text file in a batch script

Tags: windows-10, batch, script

I am trying to take the last line from a logfile and remove some text from the beginning and end of it and put it into a new text file.
I have minimal batch experience, any help is appreciated.

last line:

```
Opening track for playback: "D:\Music\musicfile.m4a"
```

Path to the logfile:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\file.log
```

What I want the last line to look like when it is done:

```
musicfile
```

Comment: include in your question the last line, the path to the logfile, and what you want the last line to look like when it is done.

Comment: that will get you started. Read [this](https://www.bing.com/search?q=parse+text+with+cmd), [this](https://www.bing.com/search?q=cmd+for+loop) and [this](https://www.bing.com/search?q=cmd+re-direction)

Comment: Add a cmd and powershell tag to your question.  Replace "To answer your question: ..." with This is what I've got so far: `@echo off  setlocal enableextensions  for /f "tokens=3 delims=\." %%g in ('type %USERPROFILE%\Documents\file.log') do set z=%%g
    echo %z%>> %USERPROFILE%\Documents\file2.log`

Add to your question: I am not set on CMD.  If you have a PowerShell solution I would like to see it.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell:

Verbose:

```
$LogFile = "$env:%USERPROFILE%\Documents\file.log"
(Get-Content -Path $LogFile | Select -Last 1) -match '.+\\([\w\s]+)\.\w{3}"$' | out-null
$matches[1]
```

At the console:

```
(gc "$HOME\Documents\file.log")[-1] -match '.+\\([\w\s]+)\.\w{3}"$'
$matches[1]
```

Alternate string manipulation:

```
$Line = (gc "$HOME\Documents\file.log")[-1]
$Line.split('"')[1].split('\')[-1].split('.')[0]
```

or even a one-liner:

```
(gc "$HOME\Documents\file.log")[-1].split('"')[1].split('\')[-1].split('.')[0]
```

[Get-Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7)

[Select-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7)

[About Regular Expressions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7)

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 64-bit. PowerShell 5.

How to parse a text file of file paths and extract basename from fullname with Powershell 5 and a regular expression (regex) and append the results to a new text file encoded in ascii.

file.log:

```
Opening track for playback: "D:\Music\musicfile1.m4a"
Opening track for playback: "D:\Music\musicfile2.mp3"
Opening track for playback: "D:\Music\musicfile3.wav" 
Opening track for playback: "D:\Music\musicfile4.mid" 
Opening track for playback: "D:\Music\musicfile5.MINIGSF"
Opening track for playback: "D:\Music\musicfile6.AIMPPL"
Opening track for playback: "D:\Music\musicfile7.L" 
Opening track for playback: "D:\Music\musicfile8.ACD-ZIP" 
Opening track for playback: "D:\Music\musicfile.m4a"
```

Path to file.log:

```
$HOME\Documents\file.log
```

What I want to extract from the last line:

```
musicfile
```

Long:

```
(Get-Content -Path $HOME\Documents\file.log | Select -Last 1) -match '.+\\([\w\s]+).+'
$matches[1] | out-file $HOME\Documents\file2.log -append -encoding ascii
```

Short:

```
(gc "$HOME\Documents\file.log")[-1] -match '.+\\([\w\s]+).+'
$matches[1] | out-file $HOME\Documents\file2.log -append -encoding ascii
```

[How to write your first PowerShell script](https://www.howtogeek.com/141495/geek-school-writing-your-first-full-powershell-script/)

[Get-Content](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell+get-content)

[Select-Object](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell+select-object)

[Regular Expressions](https://www.bing.com/search?q=regular+expressions)

[Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the files (line numbers), suggest something more direct and fast...

Try this one...

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & set "file=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\File.log"
for /f %%L in ('type "!file!" ^| find /v /c ""')do set /a "skip=%%~L-1" && (
for /f tokens^=4^delims^=^\.^" %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%more.com "!file!" +!skip!
')do echo\%%~i>"%USERPROFILE%\Documents\YourNew.log") && endlocal & goto :EOF
```

- Or, same code in normal layout:

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "file=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\File.log"

for /f %%L in ('type "!file!" ^| find /v /c ""')do set /a "skip=%%~L-1"
for /f tokens^=4^delims^=^\.^" %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%more.com "!file!" +!skip!
')do echo\%%~i>"%USERPROFILE%\Documents\YourNew.log"

endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

**1)** Use `for /f` with `find /v /c ""` to 
count how many lines in the file you have/need skip, and save it in a variable  (!skip! - 1) -> last line

```bat
for /f %%L in ('type "!file!" ^|find /v /c ""')do ( set /a "skip=%%~L-1" )
```

**2)** Additional `for /f` using multiples delimiters (`\."`) with respective escaping (`^\.^"`) for get from line output substring `\musicfile."` in tokens 4th.

```bat
for /f tokens^=4^delims^=^\.^" %%i in (...
```

**3)** Pass as an argument to command `more` how many lines should be skipped, getting the last line in the output of the looped variable

```bat
'%__APPDIR__%more.com "!file!" +!skip!'
```

**4)** Make your variable/substring to be echoed and get this
output redirects it to the target new file.

```bat
...')do echo\%%~i>"%USERPROFILE%\Documents\YourNew.log"
```

---

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**

  [√] **[More](https://ss64.com/nt/more.html)**

  [√] **[Setlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)**

  [√] **[Endlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)**

  [√] **[DelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)**

  [√] **[What is the difference between ">" and ">>" in shell command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382793/whats-is-the-difference-between-and-in-shell-command)**