# How can I take the last line from a log file and extract just the filename?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, batch, cmd.exe

I've been trying to write code in batch (powershell is also fine) to take the last line from a log file and remove some text from it, here's the logfile I'm trying to do it from:

```
Opening track for playback: "D:\Music\Mellow Vibe ● lofi study mix.m4a"
Opening track for playback: "D:\Music\Logic - Overnight.m4a"
```

It's a log from a music player program that will output whatever song is playing like this, each of the songs have various titles and I'm trying to remove the string

> Opening track for playback: "D:\Music

at the beginning of the text and the string

> .m4a"

at the end of the text. All of the files have different names but they all are in the same locations and will always begin and end the same, the only difference being the actual song/file name.

Here's the code I have, it's fairly basic code that will only fetch the last line from the log file, I'm not sure how to go about removing the text from the beginning/end of it, I would also like it to auto-update when a new song (string) is appended to the [log] file, if possible:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%a in (file.log) do (set "lastLine=%%a")
echo %lastLine%>test.txt
pause
```

Comment: Why do you keep creating new questions for the same thing??? You've been given mulitple solutions & refuse to engage those trying to help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need assistance with writing a batch script](https://superuser.com/questions/1544335/need-assistance-with-writing-a-batch-script)

Comment: please ... do not spam the site with variants of one Question. [*frown*]

Comment: So, is **PowerShell** an option? If not, why not? Batch & cmd will be obsolete at some point. There's a reason it's now the default console for the PowerUser Menu & directory context menus. If you want to learn & have fun with scripting & automation, **PowerShell** is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I take the last line from a log file and extract just the filename?

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%a in (file.log) do (
  set "lastLine=%%~na"
  )
echo %lastLine%>test.txt
endlocal
```

Example:

```
F:\test>type file.log
Opening track for playback: "D:\Music\Mellow Vibe ? lofi study mix.m4a"
Opening track for playback: "D:\Music\Logic - Overnight.m4a"

F:\test>test
F:\test>type test.txt
Logic - Overnight

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [For /f - Loop through text - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [Parameters / Arguments - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the file (line numbers), suggest something more direct and fast...

Try this one...

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & set "file=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\File.log"
for /f %%L in ('type "!file!" ^| find /v /c ""')do set /a "skip=%%~L-1" && (
for /f tokens^=4^delims^=^\.^" %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%more.com "!file!" +!skip!
')do echo\%%~i>"%USERPROFILE%\Documents\YourNew.log") && endlocal & goto :EOF
```

- Or, same code in normal layout:

```bat
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "file=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\File.log"

for /f %%L in ('type "!file!" ^| find /v /c ""')do set /a "skip=%%~L-1"
for /f tokens^=4^delims^=^\.^" %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%more.com "!file!" +!skip!
')do echo\%%~i>"%USERPROFILE%\Documents\YourNew.log"

endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

**1)** Use `for /f` with `find /v /c ""` to 
count how many lines in the file you have/need skip, and save it in a variable  (!skip! - 1) -> last line

```bat
for /f %%L in ('type "!file!" ^|find /v /c ""')do ( set /a "skip=%%~L-1" )
```

**2)** Additional `for /f` using multiples delimiters (`\."`) with respective escaping (`^\.^"`) for get from line output substring `\musicfile."` in tokens 4th.

```bat
for /f tokens^=4^delims^=^\.^" %%i in (...
```

**3)** Pass as an argument to command `more` how many lines should be skipped, getting the last line in the output of the looped variable

```bat
'%__APPDIR__%more.com "!file!" +!skip!'
```

**4)** Make your variable/substring to be echoed and get this
output redirects it to the target new file.

```bat
...')do echo\%%~i>"%USERPROFILE%\Documents\YourNew.log"
```

---

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**

  [√] **[More](https://ss64.com/nt/more.html)**

  [√] **[Setlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)**

  [√] **[Endlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)**

  [√] **[DelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)**

  [√] **[What is the difference between ">" and ">>" in shell command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382793/whats-is-the-difference-between-and-in-shell-command)**